# Why use overlapping distribution plots in python

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, plotly

My current problem is that I want to know how many likes a user receives before he/she stops opening his/her notifications.

I have tried plotting this in python using google colab. However, when using a scatter plot, no number or pattern emerges. I also tried plotting it using 2 distribution plots, with an overlap.

### python code for scatter plot

```
plot_data = [
go.Scatter(
x=merge3['user_id'],
y=merge3['notifopentotal'],
name = 'Opened Notification')]
```

### python code for distribution plot

`enable_plotly_in_cell()`

Add histogram data

```
x1 = merge3['totalLikes']
x2 = merge3['notifopentotal']
```

Group data together

```
hist_data = [x1, x2]
group_labels = ['totalLikes', 'notifopentotal']
```

Create distplot with custom bin_size

```
fig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, bin_size=10)
pyoff.iplot(fig)
```

The scatter plot resulted to disorganized lines. I was expecting to see a point of diversion, wherein the point is the number of likes a user receives before he/she stops opening her notifications.

The 2 distribution plots for likes and opened notifications overlapped in some areas and there was a point in their density curves that overlapped.

Is it safe to assume that this is the answer?